# Twitter timeline is not loading

Tags: html, css, twitter, timeline

The twitter timeline is not shown properly in the web browser even though it is the original code from the twitter publish website.
At first the timeline was shown as it should. Somehow after I refreshed the site with F5 it didn't work at all. Somehow at the X time I refreshed it worked. When I restarted my computer and wanted to work on the file again it didn't work. I'm not an expert on HTML but I think the problem may be in the script tag.

I looked up other questions here on stackoverflow but none of them helped me. My code had no problems before I tried out without the timeline.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/ErinCorleyGray/lists/stackers?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">A Twitter List by ErinCorleyGray</a> 
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

A timeline of the twitter list should be displayed instead I get only the text: "A twitter list by ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pasted your code onto a new html document and viewed it on my Chrome browser and I did not have an issue with viewing the timeline. I have attached a screenshot of what I see. Maybe it is a browser issue? [screenshot of the top of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXOJd.png)

Comment: This is strange. I tried it with brave, Firefox and Edge and none of these work.

Comment: @Hip I'm assuming that the only reason your code isn't working is because it's not running the script. Check to make sure Javascript isn't blocked by your browser settings.

Comment: That made me investigate more. So my browsers had no option active to block any scripts. But it made me think and I found out what the reason for the problem was. My VPN cybersecurity blocker was turned on and somehow blocked the timeline from working. Thank you for your help!!